# function of "member do" in rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am not quite sure I understand what the purpose of the "**member do"** block is in rails routing

```
resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items do
        member do
            patch :complete
        end
    end
  end
```

In the code above, I understand that **todo_items** is a nested resources of **todo_lists**, but I don't know what **patch :complete** is doing. All I know is that the above code grants me a new path, **complete_todo_list_todo_item_path**

Does the code have to be in a member block? What is the purpose of a member block?

Comment: It indicate that the path will be used in the scope of resource member, therefore, you can (you need) to pass ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **member block** is used when you need an extra route in your model, when you make a resource you're creating individuals (need the id of the model) and collections resources, for example: get is individual route and index is a collection route.

Now if you want another route on the same model you can use **member block for create a new individual route** or **collection block if you need a collection route**

In your example your creating a patch route for on of your todo_items that is nested on todo_lists like other resources.

Answer (score 0):

A member route will require an ID, because it acts on a member. 
In your case it will generate url somrthing like this

```
url => todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:todo_item_id/complete

helper method =>  complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(todo_list_object, todo_item_object)
```

If you define `collection` not `member` then it will not take any ID.